# Nothing happens after picking file via Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT

Tags: android, android-intent, android-videoview, onactivityresult

I'm trying to pick video from phone storage and then playing it using VideoView. Here is code how I tried to do it.

```
VideoView vvVideo;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    vvVideo = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.vvVideo);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("video/*");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);
    startActivityForResult(intent ,  11);

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == -1){
        if (requestCode == 11) {
            vvVideo.setVideoURI(data.getData());
            vvVideo.start();
        }
    }
}
```

Problem that every time I'm picking something in file_manager_activity it just restarts(I think so),and that goes on and on. I tried to debug it and process did't even go to onActivityResult. After I reopen app and than picking the file it may work from the first try,may work from the second. It's so random I can't find the pattern and where is my mistake. Sorry for my English and please help,cause I don't really know what to do.

Comment: Are you sure that resultCode is supposed to be -1(in onActivityResult)?

Comment: It ok to use -1, it is the value of RESULT_OK constant.

Comment: @MatBos I change to RESULT_OK and got the same problem. And when this loop is happening  onActivityResult never get called.

Comment: @boohaky did you check if data.getData() returns correct uri for a file?

Comment: @MatBos as I wrote onActivityResult never get called in this situations.